# Adding classes in HTML using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, I can add class name(s) to my list using pure JavaScript.

```js
var result, i;

var country = ["india", "america", "australia", "japan", "china"];

result = '<ul>';

for (i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {

  result += '<li class="test">' + country[i] + '</li>';

}

result += '</ul>';

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now, what I want is to add an extra class name to a specific item in my list.

Comment: What did you try? You can do this either inside the loop (using an `if` statement) or after your code finishes, like in @Andam's answer

Answer (score 0):

Give each list item an id like me in the for loop then get that element by id and give it a class name that you want as `document.getElementById("listItem2").className += " Specific";`

```js
var country = ["india", "america", "australia", "japan", "china"];

var result = '<ul>';

for (var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
    result += '<li class="test" id="listItem' + i + '">' + country [i] + '</li>';
}

result += '</ul>';

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
document.getElementById("listItem2").className += " Specific";
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}

.Specific {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName()` to get an array of DOM element with the specified class. Then, use `.className` to add a class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .specificItem {
        color: red; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    var  result, i;
    var country = ["india", "america", "australia", "japan", "china"];
    result = '<ul>';
    for(i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
        result += '<li class="test">' + country [i] + '</li>';
    }
    result += '</ul>';

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
    document.getElementsByClassName("test")[2].className += " specificItem";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`document.getElementsByClassName("test")[2].className += " specificItem";` gets the li element with index 2 (australia) and adds the "specificItem" class